# Passing style to my custom component is not working in react native. (styles are not attached to my custom component)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native.
I created some custom components in project. And I pass some style to them via the props but my passing styles are not attached to that components. At the first it was working correctly but suddenly I don't know what happened that my passing styles are not working.

Here is my code:

This the page where I used my custom component and passed style to that.

```
function StartGameScreen(props) {

  const [confirmed, setConfirmed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedNumber, setSelectedNumber] = useState();

  const numInputHandler = (inputText) => {
    setEneteredValue(inputText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
  };

  const confirmInput = () => {
    const chosenNumber = parseInt(enteredValue);
    if (isNaN(chosenNumber) || chosenNumber <= 0 || chosenNumber > 99) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Invalid number!",
        "Number has to be a number between 0 and 99.",
        [{ text: "Okay", style: "destructive", onPress: resetInput }]
      );
      return;
    }
    setConfirmed(true);
    setSelectedNumber(chosenNumber);
    setEneteredValue("");
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  let confirmedOutput;
  if (confirmed) {
    confirmedOutput = (
      <Card style={styles.summeryContainer}>
        <Text>You selected</Text>
        <NumberContainer>{selectedNumber}</NumberContainer>
        <Button
          title="START GAME"
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("hello" + selectedNumber);
            props.onStartGame(selectedNumber);
          }}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  }

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Start A New Game!</Text>


*This is where I used my custom component (<Card>).*
        <Card style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Text>select a number</Text>
          <Input
            style={styles.input}
            blurOnSubmit
            autoCapatilize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={2}
            onChangeText={numInputHandler}
            value={enteredValue}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonCon}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Button
                title="Reset"
                color={Colors.accent}
                onPress={resetInput}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Button
                title="Confirm"
                color={Colors.primary}
                onPress={confirmInput}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
        {confirmedOutput}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: "80%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    textAlign: "center",
    width: 50,
  },
 
});

export default StartGameScreen;
```

And this is my Card custom component:

```
 function Card(props) {
  return (
   <View style={{ ...styles.container, ...props.style }}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowRadius: 6,
    elevation: 12,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Card component like below then it will work

```
 function Card(props) {
  return (
   <View style={[styles.container,props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```